# How do you access the message content in the Thunderbird message compose window?

Tags: javascript, xul, thunderbird

I am trying to write a Thunderbird extension which will let you compose a message but it will process the message text before sending it out.  So I need access to the plain text content of the email body.

Here is what I have so far, just as some test code in the Extension Developer Javascript console.

```
var composer = document.getElementById('msgcomposeWindow');
var frame = composer.getElementsByAttribute('id', 'content-frame').item(0);
if(frame.editortype != 'textmail') {
  print('Sorry, you are not composing in plain text.');
  return;
}

var doc = frame.contentDocument.documentElement;

// XXX: This does not work because newlines are not in the string!
var text = doc.textContent;
print('Message content:');
print(text);
print('');

// Do a TreeWalker through the composition window DOM instead.
var body = doc.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0);
var acceptAllNodes = function(node) { return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT; };
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT | NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, { acceptNode: acceptAllNodes }, false);

var lines = [];

var justDidNewline = false;
while(walker.nextNode()) {
  if(walker.currentNode.nodeName == '#text') {
    lines.push(walker.currentNode.nodeValue);
    justDidNewline = false;
  }
  else if(walker.currentNode.nodeName == 'BR') {
    if(justDidNewline)
      // This indicates back-to-back newlines in the message text.
      lines.push('');
    justDidNewline = true;
  }
}

for(a in lines) {
  print(a + ': ' + lines[a]);
}
```

I would appreciate any feedback as to whether I'm on the right track.  I also have some specific questions:

- Does `doc.textContent` really not have newlines?  How stupid is that?  I'm hoping it's just a bug with the Javascript console but I suspect not.
- Is the TreeWalker correct?  I first tried `NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT` but it did not traverse into the `<SPAN>`s which contain the quoted material in a reply.  Similarly, it seems funny to `FILTER_ACCEPT` every node and then manually cherry-pick it later, but I had the same problem where if I rejected a `SPAN` node, the walker would not step inside.
- Consecutive `<BR>`s break the naive implementation because there is no `#text` node in between them.  So I manually detect them and push empty lines on my array.  Is it really necessary to do that much manual work to access the message content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, don't everybody chime in at once!

I posted this as a [mozilla.dev.extensions thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.extensions/browse_thread/thread/14357b7c8d84544c]) and there was some fruitful discussion.  I've been playing around in Venkman and the solution is to throw away my DOM/DHTML habits and write to the correct API.

```
var editor = window.gMsgCompose.editor;

// 'text/html' works here too
var text = editor.outputToString('text/plain', editor.eNone)
```

Now `text` has the plaintext version of the email body being composed.